# WPF library with page - navigation of the application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

Now I experiment with your application architecture. I have wpf library(AppView.dll MVVM) with my pages (View/MyPage.xaml).  I use this library in my wpf app. How do I set the correct URI for navigation ? I tried URI so "pack://application:,,,/AppView;View/MyPage.xaml". But there is an error - "resource not found appview;view/MyPage.xaml". How to use the navigation page from another assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `/AppView;component/View/MyPage.xaml` or  "`pack://application:,,,/AppView;component/View/MyPage.xaml"`